# Switching math fonts with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I want to use a different math font in figures (namely tikzpictures). I already asked [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123025/otf-sans-serif-math-only-in-figures) about this topic where I tried to mix [`mathspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) and [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math). Now after some reseach I realized that `mathspec` does not allow to switch the font at all and I should use only `unicode-math`.

But there I also get build errors in my MWE (or should I say MnWE, because it does not work):

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newcommand{\rmmath}{\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}}
\rmmath
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Candara}

\newcommand{\sfmath}{ %
    \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} %
    \setmathfont[range=\mathup, Numbers=Lining, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Candara} %
    \setmathfont[range=\mathit, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Candara Italic} %
    \setmathfont[range=\mathbf, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Candara Bold} %
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\sfmath}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\rmmath}

\begin{document}
% This would work, but I actually do not need sans math in running text
%   \sfmath $I$
%   \rmmath $I$
%   \sfmath $I$
%   \rmmath $I$
%   \sfmath $I$
%   \rmmath $I$
%   \sfmath $I$
%   \rmmath $I$

    Text $I$
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {Node: $I$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption text with math $I$}
    \end{figure}
    Text
% If you remove the following lines it will compile
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node {Node: $I$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{with math $I$}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Some interesting notes: if I remove the `figure` environment, i.e. only use `tikzpicture` it will build. If I use `center` instead of `figure` it also does not work. Funnily enough, if I have only **one** figure it will build.

The first error I get:

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'Candara(1)' created for font 'Candara' with options
. [BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=10-},{Size=7
.40005-10,Font=Candara,Style=MathScript},{Size=-7.40005,Font=Candara,Style=Math
ScriptScript}},Numbers={Lining},Scale={MatchUppercase}].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
.................................................

! LaTeX Error: Symbol font `um_fam1' not defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.43 ^^I\begin{tikzpicture}

Your command was ignored.
```

Comment: See also [how to select math font in document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30049/5001)

Comment: @Mico, that's right. The `version` option and `\mathversion` would be the best, unfortunately the `version` option does not work with `range`.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem.
You can partly circumvent it by using math versions, i.e.

```
\setmathfont[version=default]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} %
\setmathfont[version=sansserif, Numbers=Lining, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Candara}
```

and then use

```
\mathversion{sansserif}
```

to switch back and forth.

Math versions are however not compatible with the `range=` argument, which probably renders this approach useless. For myself I actually quickly put together a version of Tex Gyre Pagella Math which has all serif latin letters and numbers replaced by sans serif versions from Tex Gyre Heros. Not everything works, e.g. `\sqrt` has a problem, but for simple math it seems to be fine. You can download it here: http://n.ethz.ch/~thomasu/download/TeXGyrePagellaMathSans-Normal.otf

Comment: That sounds at least like a approach that works, although very hackish. How did you replaced the characters?

Comment: On my Mac I used a trial version of http://glyphsapp.com. I guess something like FontForge would also work. It needs some manual intervention though as you have to identify the parts to be replaced and then manually (I used a Python script) adjust the glyph names and unicode IDs.

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll give it at try, when I have some time.

Comment: Actually I even managed to retain the full math functionality by also transferring the MATH table entries by copying the relevant directly from one Spline Font Database Format (.sdf) file produced by FontForge to the other.