# STIX font character not displaying using MikTeX on Windows

Tags: unicode-math, stix2

The following MWE tries to display two characters from the STIX fonts (`U+1D61F` and `U+2047`).
Both are listed in
https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/blob/master/docs/STIXTwoMath-Regular.pdf

One of them displays, the other doesn't.

Why is that, and how to get around it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, final]{article}                                            

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfontface\StixTwoMath{STIX Two Math}  

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

% Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols.

\NewDocumentCommand\BCon{}{{\ensuremath{\StixTwoMath{\char"1D61F}}}}

% General Punctuation.

\NewDocumentCommand\BNc{}{{\ensuremath{\StixTwoMath{\char"2047}}}}
\NewDocumentCommand\BNq{}{{\ensuremath{\StixTwoMath{\Question}}}}                

              
\begin{document} 

\BCon{}: The \enquote{\BCon{} signifies a double.}  

\BNc{}: The \enquote{\BNc{} signifies an arbitrary bid.}   

\BNq{}: The \enquote{\BNq{} signifies an arbitrary bid.}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: do not ignore warnings `Missing character: There is no ⁇ (U+2047) in font [latinmodern-math.otf]:mode` you are using latin moder math

Comment: I think the switch to another math font should be done in another way. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128887/switching-math-fonts-with-unicode-math

Comment: Thanks David - so I am.  Not at all what I expected.!!!

Comment: Thanks for the link Martin.  In the full system I was trying to switch a (working) mess of fonts to a single one, STIX.

Comment: you have defined \StixTwoMath as a text font switch so (like `\sffamily` ) it does nothing in math, also you accessed the character via `\char` which is mainly for text so would have worked if you had not used `\ensuremath` but as you load `unicode-math`  I suspect you want to use `\setmathfont` to load stix two math

Answer (score 3):

It seems here a basically non mathematical use, so you can set up the font as a text font family

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, final]{article}                                            

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\StixTwoMath{STIX Two Math}  

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

% Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols.

\NewDocumentCommand\BCon{}{{\StixTwoMath\char"1D61F}}

% General Punctuation.

\NewDocumentCommand\BNc{}{{\StixTwoMath\char"2047}}


              
\begin{document} 

\BCon{}: The \enquote{\BCon{} signifies a double.}  

\BNc{}: The \enquote{\BNc{} signifies an arbitrary bid.}   



\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do!  Many thanks David.